# Taking a tensor product in python numpy without performing a sum

Tags: python, numpy

I have two tensors, each 2D, with a common long axis (eg 20.000) and diffenrent short axes eg one 9 the other 10). I want to end up with a 9X10X20000 tensor, such that for each location on the long axis, the other two axes are the tensor product.
Explicitly, with the "long" axis here 4, I want to do:

```
A = np.arange(8).reshape(2,4)
B = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
C = np.zeros(2,3,4)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(4):
            C[i,j,k] = A[i,k]*B[j,k]
```

This code works, but I was wondering: is there a numpy way of doing this, without running for loops?

The context is for training a neural net, with the long axis being the training examples. I get a formula of this form when calculating gradients of the cost function.
Cheers,
Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for these problems, which makes it easy to specify what should happen in terms of the indices:

```
>>> A = np.arange(8).reshape(2,4)
>>> B = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk', A, B)
array([[[ 0,  1,  4,  9],
        [ 0,  5, 12, 21],
        [ 0,  9, 20, 33]],

       [[ 0,  5, 12, 21],
        [16, 25, 36, 49],
        [32, 45, 60, 77]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This particular one you can also get to work with plain old [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
>>> A[:, np.newaxis, :] * B[np.newaxis, :, :]
array([[[ 0,  1,  4,  9],
        [ 0,  5, 12, 21],
        [ 0,  9, 20, 33]],

       [[ 0,  5, 12, 21],
        [16, 25, 36, 49],
        [32, 45, 60, 77]]])
```

The above is equivalent to the simpler:

```
>>> A[:, None] * B
array([[[ 0,  1,  4,  9],
        [ 0,  5, 12, 21],
        [ 0,  9, 20, 33]],

       [[ 0,  5, 12, 21],
        [16, 25, 36, 49],
        [32, 45, 60, 77]]])
```